# Spring data jpa, delete by collection of projections

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Something {

private String param1;

private String param2;

private String param3;

private String param4;

private String param5;

}
```

is it possible, using spring data jpa, to delete entities by list of entries of several params?

```
deleteByParam2AndParam3AndParam4In(List<SomethingDeleteProjection> projections);
```

```
public class SomethingDeleteProjection {

private String param2;

private String param3;

private String param4;

}
```

i fact what i want to is

```
delete from something where column_2 = param2, column_3 = param3, column_4 = param4;
```

but for collection of params.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use a loop of your `List<SomethingDeleteProjection> projections`. Inside that loop, delete!

Comment: Yeh, sure, but is there no way to do this in one db call?